# Using PSFTP to send file to remote server

Tags: batch-file, psftp

I have a bat file I call everynight to transfer some files.

I want to put a file from my computer to my remote server. 
I have installed PSFTP and I don't know how to use it in batch way.

I put this :

```
CD /D C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop
psftp user@99.99.99.99 -pw password -P port
put file.csv /remote/folder/file.csv
```

But when I call my BAT file, it stucks on :

```
psftp > _
```

How can I use it as automate mode ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets diagnose why it does not work.

1. Batch file starts. Probably in C:\users\vincent\
2. Working directory gets changed by the first command. this command finishes and the processing moves on to the next command.
3. `psftp user@99.99.99.99 -pw password -P port` get started. It is running and waiting for user input.
4. The next *command* does not get reached until the previous one ends. If you are a quick reader then you can type `quit` and see a the error message that `put is not a recognised internal or external command` before the windows closes.

Ok, so we now found that we are issueing a third command rather than input for psftp. The question now is how you can issue orders to the running psftp program.

[Chapter 6](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html), section 6.1.5 of psftp meanion the `-b` option. Quoting that:

*In normal operation, PSFTP is an interactive program which displays a command line and accepts commands from the keyboard. If you need to do automated tasks with PSFTP, you would probably prefer to specify a set of commands in advance and have them executed automatically.  The -b option allows you to do this. You use it with a file name containing batch commands. For example, you might create a file called myscript.scr containing lines like this:*

It then lists an example. In your case the file probably should contain this:

```
put file.csv /remote/folder/file.csv
quit
```